# Chrome characters substitution

Tags: google-chrome, text, google-chrome-extension, substitution

Is there a way or extension that allow to automatically substitute some characters by another expression, like "Mac > Settings > Keyboard > Text" : "Replace xxx by yyyy", for example to automatically substitute "rg" by "Regards" when hitting 'r g  ?

I already tried on Mac, but this feature is only available in Mac Apps (Mail, Keynote, TexEdit...), so i would appreciate to enable it on entire Chrome app, websites, forms, text area...

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this feature (text substitution) is not supported yet by Google Chrome.

You can star this issue (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42434) to upvote the feature request.

The closest thing I can find is a Chrome plugin called [Popchrom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popchrom/iinhokidgfoomcighckbjmlcndbjmomp?hl=en) which allows you to define shortcuts similarly like text substitution. However, for this plugin:

1) you have to define your shortcuts once again

2) it doesn't work outside Chrome

3) it doesn't work inside Chrome in some places, such as the address bar

4) after entering your shortcut, you have to hit a key combo like "Ctrl-Space" to trigger the expansion

5) its UI is far from beautiful

But it is free and at least it works in most cases you need text expansion in Chrome.

Comment: Don't forget to use the Send Feedback link in Chrome and send Google team a link to the bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42434 -- they succeeded ignoring it for more than 6 years. So far, Chrome is the only application on Mac OS that has this bug.